# Greedy algorithm , the coin change problem proof

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science

How to proof that a greedy algorithm will work on this set of coins $ S = {1,2,3...K} $.
I haven't  seen a proof on this type of sets but saw on this set $1,5,10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greedy algorithm will use $\lceil \frac nK\rceil$ coins. Any better method would use $r$ coins for some $r$ with $rK<n$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is an algorithm that in some case gives an answer that includes two coins $a$ and $b$ with $a,b<K$. If $a+b\le K$, then the two coins can be replaced with one coin, which would mean the algorithm is not optimal. If $a+b>K$, then you can replace the two coins by a $K$ coin and a $a+b-K$ coin for an equally good solution using more of the value $K$ coins.

Therefore, any optimal algorithm can without loss of generality be assumed to use at most one coin that is not of value $K$. There is only one way to do this for any total value, and this is the same as the solution that the greedy algorithm gives.